# UIView.animate Ignoring duration on custom pop I created. Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

```
let bigView = UIViewController()
let pView = UIView()

extension UIViewController {
    
    func showPopUp() {
        
        
        bigView.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
        self.present(bigView, animated: false, completion: nil)
        
        let bColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        blurView.frame = bigView.view.bounds
        blurView.backgroundColor = bColor
        bigView.view.addSubview(blurView)
        
        pView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 180)
        if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            pView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9778117069, green: 0.9778117069, blue: 0.9778117069, alpha: 1) } else {pView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2506543464, green: 0.2506543464, blue: 0.2506543464, alpha: 1)}
        pView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        pView.isOpaque = false
        pView.center = blurView.center
        blurView.addSubview(pView)
        
        pView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        pView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
            pView.alpha = 1
            pView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Hey guys here is a shortened version of my code, not sure why its not animating with a duration... when I click the button I have assigned it just jumps the scale to (scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1).. instead of gradually animating. Any idea why ?

Comment: What's `blurView`?

Comment: i actually found the solution. I had to put the animation inside dispatchque with a tiny delay. 
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
                pView.alpha = 1
                pView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil) }`